# gd library gives broken image and overrides wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, gd

I have created a new template and added the following code:

```
<?php
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('images/haz.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/baz.jpg');

$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

For some reason this just overrides my entire theme and gives me a broken image https://i.stack.imgur.com/vheLR.png

I've also tried some other codes I've found and the results are the same! My theme is gone and all I see is a broken image. This leads me to believe that there is something wrong with my server or my GD library. 
I used phpinfo and this is what I got

```
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.3.11
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPG Support enabled
PNG Support enabled
WBMP Support    enabled
XPM Support enabled
XBM Support enabled
```

What bothers me more is that it doesn't only show a broken image but also overrides my entire theme! I've tried looking for a solution in google for hours but can't seem to find one!

Comment: Remove the `header` call and right-click your broken image and choose "View image". Your image doesn't show up because there is probably a PHP error message wrote in the output buffer.

Answer (score 0):

It will be the GD library hiting a fatal error, and probably dying/exiting.